# Unable to load data into redshift tables using python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

This is the python code that I am using to load data into redshift. However although I do not get any error messages I don't see data within my redshift tables. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import calendar
import time
import sys
import os
import datetime
from datetime import date

yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print (yesterday)

tablename = ["customers", "payments", "dept"]    

con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'dbname', host='hostname',
port= '17500', user= 'user', password= 'pwd', sslmode = 'require')

cur = con.cursor()

for i in range(len(tablename)):
    copy_command = """copy "public"."{tablename}" from 's3://PATH/prefix/{tablename}/{}/{}/{}/' 
    iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxxxx'
    format as parquet;""".format(yesterday.year, yesterday.month, yesterday.day, tablename = tablename[i])

    print (copy_command)
   

    
    cur.execute(copy_command)
    con.commit()

#Close the cursor and the connection
con.close()
```

Comment: Can you try adding "connect_timeout" parameter in connection options, its value is in seconds and keep it based on the amount of data it is going to load to redshift.

Comment: I tried adding that string with
con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'dbname', host='hostname',
port= '17500', user= 'user', password= 'pwd', sslmode = 'require', , options='-c statement_timeout=5000')  --This didn't work

I also tried 

con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'dbname', host='hostname',
port= '17500', user= 'user', password= 'pwd', sslmode = 'require',connect_timeout=5000) --This also didn't work and I didn't see the data in the table

The query also doesn't appear to have run either when I checked redshift